# Handle multiple className in makeStyle() - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to handle multiple className(s) to customize the style of the HTML element, but i don't understand how I can replicate the situation `.class1.class2` (css) with the `makeStyle` method of React.

The situation is pretty simple, I've some blocks with className `slide` and one of them will always be `active` (so className=({classes.slide: true}, {classes.active: true})

In css I would've defined in such a way:

```css
.slide {
  <some styles>
}

.slide.active {
  <some other styles>
}
```

Can i do something similar with `makeStyle()` or should I replace `{classes.active: true}` with `{classes.activeSlide: true}` and handle the situation like the following:

```js
slide: {
  <some styles>
},

activeSlide: {
  <some other slide>
},
```

Answer (score 10):

`:active` is a pseudo class.
`makestyles` provides the solution for all psuedo classes as follows:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
 slide: {
  color: '#000',

  '&:active': {
   color: '#fff'
  }
 }
)})
```

Also, when using `makeStyles` you have to call `const classes = useStyles()` to get access to use the class names like `classes.slide` as the value of the `className` attribute in any jsx/html element in the render method.

**EDIT/UPDATE**:

In material ui `makeStyles` method, 
You want to write a common style rule for multiple classes when an element has both the classes attributed to it. So, for material ui `makeStyles` method, you can define multiple classes inside `makeStyles` like:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
 class1: {
  marginTop: 100,
 },
 class2: {}
}))
```

Also attach them to the element using template literal like:

```
<div className={`${classes.class1} ${classes.class2}`}>
```

Now, to make `class1` and `class2` work as a combination we can do this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
 class1: {
  marginTop: 100,

  '&$class2': {
   color: 'red'
  }

 },
 class2: {}
}))
```

so even if `class2` is not required in isolation, we need to define a dummy object so that we can have access to it when required inside `render` using `classes.class2` and if required you can add styles to it which will work as any other className.

Also, found a documentation reference to this [here](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet) .

Comment: If you want to just access multiple classes as the className value, simple use template strings like `className={`${classes.slide} ${classes.slide2}`}`

Comment: Yeah, of course. But I called the className active beacuse it's on an element as a property, not really a status, so I can't use the pseudo class `:active`.
I've a slider with 5 slides; I should shift it and show the one with the "active" class, so i wanted apply a style on the slide element, with className `slide` but the only one that is shown, so that also has the `active` className.

Comment: ok so i think you can achieve in the same way i mentioned because template literals can evaluate a js expression so you can apply multiple classes conditionally like 
`className: { ${classes.slide} ${ isActive ? classes.slide2 : '' }}`

Comment: I don't really have a problem piling up classes to my element/component, but i don't know how to apply my style on an element that has both the className(s).
Something that, in css, I would do like this, but that I don-t know how to realize with `makeStyles()`:
```css
.class1.class2 {
  ...
}
```

Comment: updated my answer . Hopefully this update finally solves your question. @SamueleMarchisio

Comment: Here's the docs for the specifics on how to use makestyles: https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#with-material-ui-core the solution was also described here

Answer (score 1):

You can access your current classname inside its value object using the '&' character. Here is how it would look like in your case:

```js
const classes = {
  slide: {
    backgroundColor: 'teal',

    '&.active': {
       backgroundColor: 'gold'
     }

  }
}
```

Comment: Already tried, but it would work with a normal class, not a `className`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate your classes by a space string like this:

- Between two makeStyles classes:

```
className = {classes.class1 + ' ' + classes.class2 }
```

- Between a MakeStyle class and a CSS class:

```
className ={classes.class1 + ' ' +  'cssClass'}
```

```
                      OR
```

```
className ={classes.class1 + ' cssClass'}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

**first option** :

`yarn add clsx` is utility for constructing className strings conditionally

**second option** :

`className={${classes.slide} ${classes. activeSlide}}`

Comment: You should edit your post to add some detail explaining your solution.

Comment: That's not the real deal. The problem is apply a style on an element that has both the className(s) "class1" and "class2".
In css I'd do `.class1.class2 {...}`, but that could not be done with Material UI's `makeStyle()`.